# Android studio items copied cannot be refactored because they are linked

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have had to do a lot of copying and pasting of my layouts and items in them. If I copy and paste these and then try to refactor their names they also change the names of all of my copies. This happens in the xml code editor or in my design editor. Could someone tell me what this is called and how can I copy and paste without having the items be linked? I am so frustrated. Thanks!

For example if I have a textview with and Id of "tv" and then I copy the block of xml and paste it elsewhere to use the same block and then refactor to rename it's id then both the original and copy will update. I want to paste a version of the textview that is NOT linked like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `android:id="@+id/foo"` in your layout file, the system will wind up generating an `int` value in a file called `R.java`, something like `R.id.foo = 0x7f123456`.

When you then write `android:id="@+id/foo"` again in a different file, that will reference the same `R.id.foo` int. So, when you use the refactoring tools, all instances of `@id/foo` are considered.

Perhaps you can use the simple textual Find/Replace action instead of Refactor -> Rename.

Answer (score 0):

The copies aren't "linked". They just use the same names, so if you try to refactor the copy, then Android Studio finds that name in the original and will rename it. Instead, you will have to edit your copies manually without using the Android Studio refactoring tools.

Another option if you are using version control is to do the rename refactor then undo the local, uncommitted changes in the original files with Ctrl+Alt+Z.